# What is the Best way to assign attributes by their index

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr

I have a wrapper which has children which all need specific positions.

Let's say I have a markup like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider" data-position=""></div>
    <div class="slider" data-position=""></div>
    <div class="slider" data-position=""></div>
</div>
```

The last child should have a position of infront, the second last child should have a position of behind and every other slider should have a position of limbo.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Lpp/1/

I'm really not a fan of the massive chain of if and else statements....

Is there a better more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: A side note: instead of `currentItem.attr('data-position', 'behind');` do `currentItem.data('position', 'behind');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sliders = $("div.slider").data("position", "limbo");
sliders.last().data("position", "infront");
sliders.eq(-2).data("position", "behind");
```

---

**EDIT:** Using classes:

```
var sliders = $("div.slider").removeClass("limbo infront behind");
sliders.last().addClass("infront");
sliders.eq(-2).addClass("behind");
sliders.slice(0, -2).addClass("limbo");
```

Comment: This works, and you know what, of course a very similar idea just ca,e to my mind moments after posting this... haha thankyou, I'll stick to the attr command though because I need the values visible for css :)

Comment: I would have thought that trying to select something using eq(-2), if it doesn't exist it would throw an error, but nope, good work jquery. lol

Comment: Does this mean you are doing something like `[data-position=infront] { ... }` in your CSS? Use classes instead then.

Comment: jQuery won't **ever** throw on valid selectors, remember it works on sets, so everything that doesn't exist just gives you an empty set. It's one of the main reasons it's so much more friendly than pure DOM.

Comment: @christian314159, if I use classes, then I'd have to remove the current classes before adding them, as well as making sure that I keep my slider class, using an alternate attribute is handy here.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins you can call `.removeClass("limbo infront behind")`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski but is that not less elegant and just more code?

Comment: I'd say using CSS classes is more elegant for styling than using data attributes, and it will make your CSS more elegant too. It's just one more line where you clear everything, no big deal.

Comment: It's not one more line though @LucasTrzesniewski? it'd be several?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of the item relative to the last item, and calculate the position from that:

```
var index = currentItem.index() - sliders.length;
currentItem.attr('data-position',
    index == -1 ? 'infront' :
    index == -2 ? 'behind' :
    'limbo'
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5Lpp/2/

Comment: I didn't even know you could chain inline statements that way, cool but I'll go with Lucas idea.